# Displaying email in iOS 8

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I have some very basic HTML emails that I'm sending site users through AWS SES (registration, password reset, etc). The emails display as expected in every client I've tested on, except iOS 8's Mail app on my iPhone 5, where it displays a blank screen. The weird part is that all the elements are there- I can copy and paste the text, download the images, and access all the links, based on the space they should occupy on the screen- they're just invisible. I've ruled out phone/inbox issues as these are the only emails that are doing this, but it's every single one of them.

Email body is parsed from Jade templates, here is a sample:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Page title
    style(type='text/css') a:active, a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: none;color: #777; } a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #999;cursor:hand; } 
  body(style="font-family:'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:200")
    table(width="100%" height="100%")
      table(width="100%" style="height:100px;text-align:center;background:#000;box-shadow:0 0 6px #999")
        tr(width="100%" height="100%")
          td(width="100%" height="100%" style='vertical-align:middle')
            img(src='https://header-image')
      table(width="100%")
        tr(width="100%")
          td(width="100%" style="padding:50px; font-size:1em; color:#333;text-align:left")
            p Text and links
      table(width="100%" height="24px" style="text-align:center;background:#000;box-shadow:0 0 6px #999")
        tr(width="100%" height="100%")
          td(width="100%" height="100%")
            p
              a(href='https://social-media-link') 
                img(src='https://social-media-image')
```

Ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Is this the correct html code? HTML tags has to be <html><a><table> like this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - it was a CSS issue. Once I changed all CSS to inline and removed the stylesheet, it worked fine.